# Replace identical placeholders in a string using an array of replacement strings

Tags: php, string, replace, placeholder, formatted-text

I have a text:

`foo {{bar}} foo {{bar}} foo`

I have an array:

```
$bar[0] = 'lol';
$bar[1] = 'kek';
```

I want to have this result:

`foo lol foo kek foo`

I tried this:

```
preg_replace("/{{bar}}/usi",$bar,$text);
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can get your desired result by iterating through your replacements array, using the `limit` parameter to [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to prevent it replacing more than 1 value at a time:

```
foreach ($bar as $b) {
    $string = preg_replace('/{{bar}}/usi', $b, $string, 1);
}

echo $string;
```

Output:

```
foo lol foo kek foo
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/r5Pgc)

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) together with [`array_shift`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php).

```
$res = preg_replace_callback('/{{bar}}/', function($m) use (&$bar) {
  return array_shift($bar);
}, $str);
```

- to modify `$bar` from inside the callback function, it's `&`[passed by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)
- for the anonymous Callback function to work, you'd probably need PHP v5.4+

[Here is a demo at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/l4LI5)

Answer (score 0):

Use language-compatible placeholders instead of `{{bar}}`, then print with native function `vprintf()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/m9ZC6))

```
$string = 'foo {{bar}} foo {{bar}} foo';

$bar = ['lol', 'kek'];

vprintf(str_replace('{{bar}}', '%s', $string), $bar);
```

Output:

```
foo lol foo kek foo
```